# How to translate WooCommerce product attribute with polylang

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to translate WooCommerce product attribute translable with polylang plugin. How can I do that?

Comment: Have  you installed Woocommerce Polylang Integration plugin yet? The best alternatives are first WPML and after qTranslate plugins. With polylang you will have a lot of issues…

Comment: Have you figured this out?

Comment: @Savan why are you asking to be more specific? the question is simple and clear. I see too many times Stackoverflow collaborators ask for "more clarity" where the question is extremely clear. If you don't know the answer, just don't post a reply.